# How do I take serialize a generic type T to a byte array using guava and gson?

Tags: gson, guava

```
 private Function serialize(final Class<?> clazz, T type){
        Function<T, byte[]> serializer = new Function<T, byte[]>(){
            @Override
            public byte[] apply(final T type) {
                return gson.toJson(type, clazz).getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
            }
        };

       return serializer;
    }
```

How do I write a class that can take in a generic type "T" and serialize it to a byte array using guava function and gson. The above gives me compiler errors.

Comment: And the errors are? Why does the method return a raw type?

Comment: It is a compilation error that doesn't suggest anything. I want it to return the parameterized type too. How do I modify this ?

Comment: Just because it doesn't suggest anything to *you* doesn't mean it's useless.

Comment: It says "T" cannot be resolved to a type on the left and "Add unimplemented methods on right" of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

"T can't be resolved to a type" means that the compiler can't fine the type T. And indeed, I doubt you defined a class named T. T is supposed to be a generic type of the method, but you haven't made the method generic. To be generic, it should be declared as

```
private <T> Function serialize(final Class<?> clazz, T type)
```

And you don't want to return the raw Function type, and the `Class` argument should, I guess, be a `Class<T>` and not any class. So it should be declared as

```
private <T> Function<T, byte[]> serialize(final Class<T> clazz, T type)
```

Comment: T can also be any type like String, integer etc right?

Comment: I actually want serialize to return a byte array, will this declaration allow me to return a byte[] array?

Comment: No. This declaration says that the method returns a `Function<T, byte[]>`. You would have to invoke the function's `apply()` method with `type` as argument to make it return a byte array.